# Evolution of volumes in Phase-Space

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, time-evolution, volume

[Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) states that the volume occupied by an ensemble does not change as the ensemble evolves. My question regards the volume of the smallest sphere that contains the ensemble. Is there a way to calculate how the volume of such sphere evolves with time?

Comment: Do you mean the small*est* sphere?

Comment: Yes, I do, tankyou

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of Liouville is the constancy of any 2-forms of canonically conjugate pairs of position and momentum

$$dx_i \wedge dp_i.$$

So for a single particle system the spherical coordinates

$$dr\wedge dp_r$$

is a measure for the frequency that the path in phase space is passing a spherical shell $(r,r+dr)$ at a radial momentum in $(p_r,p_r+dp_r)$ : the larger the spatial sphere the smaller is the radial momentum.

Without specifying the Hamiltonian this only another expression for the Hamiltonian flow in any coordinate system being a rotation locally:

$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = \partial_{p_r} H, \ \ \frac{d p_r}{dt} = -\partial_r H$$

Comment: Hey, thakyou for your reply, but I see that I wasn't clear. I mean a sphere in Phase space

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be said in general. The phase space volume can only by contained if the volume is finite and the total of potential energies does not allow for infinite momentum production. Eg for a gravitational bounded system of negative total energy contained in a spatial sphere and by finite kinetic energy distribution contained in a momentum sphere at t=0, cannot be contained, if particles can aquire infinitely high kinetic energy at the cost of pair potential energy and leave the spatial sphere.

Few particle systems with a compact start distibution in phase space tend to evolve into a topological foam without boundaries, just any part and the total volume is conserved. Prototype of measurable sets with no describable structure.

Comment: Yes, but suppose the max distance (in phase space) among the initial states of the ensemble is $2r_0$, that means that all the ensemble is contained inside a sphere of radious $r_0$, I would like to know, if given a Hamiltonian, is possible to describe the evolution of such radious as the system evolves r(t)

Comment: To clarify, My final goal is to have a definition of evolution of entropy in some sense, motivated by coarse-graining. I am describing the uncertainty of the initial state as an ensemble, and would like to know how this uncertainty evevolves with the system in a loose sense, using these spheres. The evolution of the volume of the sphere would describe (hopefully) the evolution of entropy of the system (again, in a loose sense).

Comment: This should be related to th e lyapunov's exponents, but I don't immediately see how

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is an very old one. Canonical time evolution conserves any geometrically fixable dpdx-volumes in phase space. So entropy is conserved. Coarse graining is a forget functor on ensembles, so not the single system gains entropy, but the ensemble descriptor by the not always attentive observers. Similar thoughts apply to the Botzmann ansatz. Somehow one has to introduce a truly random process in order to increase entropy. Thats conventionally done by contact with an infinite system in thermal equilibrium at least on paper.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).